# jQuery On-screen-keyboard on demand

Tags: jquery, web-applications, keyboard, point-of-sale, on-screen-keyboard

I'm writing an web-application (EPoS) that will be used on touch screen computers that will not have a keyboard on them, so I am utilizing https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/ to be able to offer an on screen keyboard when needed in the application (saves having microsoft's version open all the time).

My issue is, how can I call the keyboard to open when I want it to instead of (by default) when it is focused on. I plan to always have a field focused on the page to allow for a barcode scanner to input when it wants, but I also want to have a button next to it allowing the user to open the OSK to manually enter a product barcode number.

I've read through the documentation but can't see a way of doing this, has anyone else got any idea's?

Comment: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Methods#reveal -- isn't that what you want?

Comment: Thats half the answer, now to figure out how to prevent .focus() revealing the keyboard. Thanks for your input so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the option openOn

```
 // Event (namespaced) on the input to reveal the keyboard. To disable it, just set it to ''.
```

So in your keyboard options set

```
openOn : ''
```

Good luck

Comment: Yes, I figured this one out afterwards.